# How to create a Swift Regex that outputs a custom type?

Tags: swift, regex, swift-regexbuilder

In the [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110358), it was shown that you can do something like this with `Capture`s/`TryCapture`s in the Regex Builder:

```
let regex = Regex {
  // ...

  TryCapture {
    OneOrMore(.digit)
  } transform: {
    Int($0)
  }

  // ...
}
```

And the output of the `Regex` will be type safe. The `Regex` will output an `Int` for that group, instead of a `Substring` like it normally does.

However, what I would like to do is to change the entire output type of the whole `Regex`, like applying a `transform:` at the end of the `Regex` closure. For example, to parse a line containing the name, age and date of birth of a person:

```
John (30) 1992-09-22
```

I would like to do something like:

```
// this doesn't work and is just for illustration - there is no such Regex.init
let regex = Regex {
    Capture(/\w+/)
    " ("
    TryCapture(/\d+/) { Int($0) }
    ") "
    Capture(.iso8601Date(timeZone: .gmt))
} transform: { (_, name, age, dob) in
    Person(name: String(name), age: age, dob: dob)
}
```

And I would expect `regex` be of type `Regex<Person>`, and not `Regex<(Substring, Substring, Int, Date)>`. That is, `someString.wholeMatch(of: regex).output` would be a string, not a tuple.

I'm basically just trying to reduce the occurrence of tuples, because I find it very inconvenient to work with them, especially unnamed ones. Since `RegexComponent` is parameterised by the unconstrained `RegexOutput` type, and there are built-in types where `RegexOutput` is `Date` and `Decimal`, surely doing this for arbitrary types using regex is not impossible, right?

My attempt was:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let dob: Date
}
let line = "John (30) 1992-09-22"
let regex = Regex {
    Capture {
        Capture(/\w+/)
        " ("
        TryCapture(/\d+/) { Int($0) }
        ") "
        Capture(.iso8601Date(timeZone: .gmt))
    } transform: { (_, name, age, dob) in
        Person(name: String(name), age: age, dob: dob)
    }
}
line.wholeMatch(of: regex)
```

but this crashed at runtime, giving the message:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Substring' (0x7ff865e3ead8) to '(Swift.Substring, Swift.Substring, Swift.Int, Foundation.Date)' (0x7ff863f2e660).

Another attempt of mine using `CustomConsumingRegexComponent` is shown [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73809773/5133585), but that has quite a large caveat, namely that it doesn't backtrack properly.

How can I create a `Regex` that outputs my own type?

Comment: Can the solution work without nesting? Please, see the example below.

Comment: I have hit the same desire and problem.  Nested captures don't seem to get passed as a tuple to the parent capture transform - just the raw string that matched.

Comment: `.mapOutput` seems like it should do what we but Xcode 15.1b1 isn't finding that defined on Regex.  https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0351-regex-builder.md#mapping-output

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-experimental-string-processing/pull/466

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read/seen in samples (e.g. [swift-regex](https://bignerdranch.com/blog/swift-regex/)), it might be a good idea to create a regex component similar to `.word`, `.digit`, but nesting `captures` does not seem to work easily.

Here is an example run in the playground to create a `Person struct` instance:

```
public static func regexBuilderMatching(string: String = "John (30) 1992-09-22") {

    struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
        let name: String
        let age: Int
        let dob: Date

        public func dobToFormatterString() -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            // 1992-09-22 04:00:00 +0000
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: self.dob)
        }
        
        var description: String {
            return "\(name), age: \(age), has dob: \(dobToFormatterString())"
        }
    }

    func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .none // removes time from date
        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        formatter.dateFormat = "y-MM-d" // 1992-09-22
        return formatter.date(from: dateString)
    }

    let regexWithBasicCapture = Regex {
        /* 1. */ Capture { OneOrMore(.word) }
        /* 2. */ " ("
        /* 3. */ TryCapture { OneOrMore(.digit) }
                    transform: { match in
                        Int(match)
                    }
        /* 4. */ ") "
        /* 5. */ TryCapture { OneOrMore(.iso8601Date(timeZone: .gmt)) }
                    transform: { match in
                        dateFromString(dateString: String(match))
                    }
    }

    let matches = string.matches(of: regexWithBasicCapture)
    for match in matches {
        // shorthand syntax using match output
        // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex/match
        let (_, name, age, date) = match.output
        let person = Person(name: String(name), age: age, dob: date)
        print(person)
    }
}
```

The above code will output:

```
John, age: 30, has dob: 1992-09-22
```